# In rails how can I send an AJAX request without a ? in the data?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to send a `GET` request to my `/routes/` controller so I can receive some data back, right now I have

```
function fetchMarker(id) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/routes/',
        data: id,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

But the problem is is when I do that, Firebug tells me:

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://10.0.0.24:3000/routes/?15"`

I believe this is being caused by the ?, I've recently switched to Ruby on Rails so I don't know if this is normal but rake routes tells me it has to be /routes/(params[:id]) so I'm assuming just the ID number.

My controller:

```
def show
    @route = Route.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @route }
    end

end
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just append the `id` to the `url`, instead of sending it as `data`:

```
function fetchMarker(id) {
  var data;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/routes/' + id,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
}
```